# How to fill image grid from array of images

Tags: html, twig

I have designed a layout for an image grid with 9 images. I want to loop through my array of images and fill the grid dynamically so that the 10th image starts a new grid and is styled like the first image, 11th like the second image and so on...
The array won't always contain a multiple of 9.

This is what I currently have: (with fixed array indexes to show the order of images)

```
<div class="widget-body">
  {% for mediaItem in mediaItems|batch(9) %}
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
      <div class="col-12 p-0">
        <img class="w-100" src="{{ (mediaItems[0].getWebPath()) }}" alt="{{ mediaItems[0].title }}"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
      <div class="col-6 p-0">
        <div class="customGrid-background-img customGrid-rectangle" style="background-image: url('{{ (mediaItems[1].getWebPath()) }}')"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 p-0">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
          <div class="col-6 p-0 customGrid-background-img customGrid-square" style="background-image: url('{{ (mediaItems[2].getWebPath()) }}')"></div>
          <div class="col-6 p-0 customGrid-background-img customGrid-square" style="background-image: url('{{ (mediaItems[3].getWebPath()) }}')"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
      <div class="col-6 p-0">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
          <div class="col-6 p-0 customGrid-background-img customGrid-square" style="background-image: url('{{ (mediaItems[4].getWebPath()) }}')"></div>
          <div class="col-6 p-0 customGrid-background-img customGrid-square" style="background-image: url('{{ (mediaItems[5].getWebPath()) }}')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
          <div class="col-6 p-0 customGrid-background-img customGrid-square" style="background-image: url('{{ (mediaItems[6].getWebPath()) }}')"></div>
          <div class="col-6 p-0 customGrid-background-img customGrid-square" style="background-image: url('{{ (mediaItems[7].getWebPath()) }}')"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 p-0">
        <div class="customGrid-background-img customGrid-square" style="background-image: url('{{ (mediaItems[8].getWebPath()) }}')"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I have 10 images in the `mediaItems` array, which results in the grid being shown twice with the first 9 images.

Comment: Have a look into [batch](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/batch.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use a `fill` argument with the batch filter to be able to use the second batch.

```
{% for mediaItem in mediaItems|batch(9, 'empty') %}
```

I also accidentally used `mediaItems` for the images. It should be `mediaItem` (for example: `background-image: url('{{ (mediaItem[1].getWebPath()) }}')`)